# Running Fakes with 3rd party coverage tools

Tags: moles, microsoft-fakes, ncover, opencover, partcover

Is it possible to use Microsoft Fakes with 3rd party code-coverage tools such as NCover, PartCover or OpenCover?

With Moles this was possible using the CLRMONITOR_EXTERNAL_PROFILERS environment variable but it doesn't work with Fakes so I was wondering if the environment variable had changed name - if so I can't find out what this is.

Comment: [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) now supports Fakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to enable another profiler together with Fakes.

Comment: Yup, it seems you are right. Seems a shame they removed support, looks like we'll have to provide the support ourselves.